# Ten extra UITableViewCellContentViews appear blank and stacked on top of each other in the TableView. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, rx-swift

Ten extra UITableViewCellContentViews appear blank and stacked on top of each other in the TableView. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. You mentioned that you have defined cells above and below, but 10 empty cells are still appearing. I'm not sure why this is happening. Is there anyone who can help?

[image]

Comment: What is the output of the observable that feeds the table view? What sort of DataSource are you using?

Comment: I am making 2 API requests to the server.

First of
let section = SectionModel<DKSection,DKSectionItem>(model: DKSectionAdapter(identifier: "", title: "", height: 0), items: [result])
                    var sections = self?.data.value ?? []
                    sections.insert(section, at: 0)
                    self?.data.accept(sections)

Comment: Second of 
let section = SectionModel<DKSection,DKSectionItem>(model: DKSectionAdapter(identifier: "", title: "", height: 0), items: response.data)
                        var sections = self?.data.value ?? []
                        if sections.count > 1 {
                            sections.popLast()
                        }
                        sections.append(section)
                        self?.data.accept(sections)

Comment: I have implemented the structure on a TableViewCell. Inside the first cell, there is a UICollectionView. I set the data obtained from the first API call to this UICollectionView. For the other cells, I sequentially display the data returned from the second API call.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there. Also, put a `.debug()` just before your `.bind(items:)` call and show what the debug outputs in the question. I'll be able to help more with that information.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that jumps out at me based on the code you posted in the comments is that both sections have the same identifier of `""`. That won't do. Every section has to have a unique identifier.

More help will require more code.